# Create object using linq on windows phone

Tags: linq-to-xml

This is a sample of the xml I´m using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
<tbody>
<tr class="group">

<td class="team"><span>1</span> <a href="link">Jeans</a></td>
<td class="a">
<p>10</p>
</td>
<td class="b">
<p>20</p>
</td>
<td class="team"><span>1</span> <a href="link">T-shirt</a></td>
<td class="a">
<p>20</p>
</td>
<td class="b">
<p>20</p>
</td>
</tr>
```

I need to create a object and populate it with the data coming from the xml.
I´ve already the class with all the properties needed and I´m using this linq code to read the xml:

```
var searched = from c in xml.Descendants("tbody").Descendants("tr").Descendants("td").Descendants("a")
                           from cc in xml.Descendants("tbody").Descendants("tr").Descendants("td") where (cc.Attribute("class").Value == "a")
                           select new Time
                           {
                               name = c.Value,
                               data = cc.Value
                           };
```

Im using this foreach to iterate:

```
foreach (var item in searched)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(item.name + item.data);
                listBox1.Items.Add("  ");
```

Shouldnt I get a result like this?

Jeans 10 -
T-Shirt 10

Instead Im getting:
Jeans 10 -
Jeans 20 -
T-Shirt 10 -
T-Shirt 20 -

Is this linq statement wrong? How can I create an object with these values coming from the xml?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract from your XML? From what I gather, you have rows like this `[Jeans|10|20|T-shirt|20|20]`. Are there more rows like this? Do you always want to extract the label and the first number?

Comment: @madd0 Yes, I want to extrac the value inside the <a> tag and its corresponding value in <td class="a">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your final goal is, but I'd do something like this:

```
XElement table = xml.Descendants("tbody").First();

var searched = from c in table.Descendants("tr")
               let team = c.Descendants().First()
               select new
               {
                   Name = team.Descendants("a").First().Value,
                   PG = c.Descendants("td").Where(td => (string)td.Attribute("class") == "tc-pg").First().Value,
                   J = c.Descendants("td").Where(td => (string)td.Attribute("class") == "tc-j").First().Value,
                   V = c.Descendants("td").Where(td => (string)td.Attribute("class") == "tc-v").First().Value,
                   // and so on...
               };
```

And then add the items to the list:

```
foreach (var item in searched)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", item.Name, item.PG);
    listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", item.Name, item.J);
    listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", item.Name, item.V);

    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: Im getting a System.InvalidOperationException in the data attribute.
Maybe my example was not very clear. 
I want the final result to be:
Jeans - 10
        20
T-shirt - 20
          20
The value of the cloth must not repeat (jeans, t-shirt), and the values in the <td> must be shown according to the cloth related

Comment: I edited my answer to better fit your expected output, but, once again, your sample is limited, so it's hard to guarantee that a given query will always work.

Comment: Its gotten a little confused. Would you like to see the real xml?

Comment: @DiegoVin it would help if you could pastebin it, yes

Comment: cant paste here. its a yql link and the link format goes crazy. any mail I could send the link?

Comment: I´ve figured out how to do it with the:
where c.Attribute("class").Value == "a" || c.Attribute("class").Value == "b" filtering.  Is there a was than I can filter this inside the select statement? this would solve the problem...

Comment: Your sample data doesn't really look like your real data. I created a link to it in your question. It would also help if you could. I'm not sure I understand the question in your previous comment, but I suspect that if I knew what your `Time` class really looks like, it would be clearer.

Comment: Class time is not finished yet... I was first trying to get the data from the xml before completing it. Can u move this discussion to chat? I cant do it due to lack of reputation...

Comment: You can't chat, even if I invite you, try this service: http://tinychat.com/d00lp

Comment: worked perfectly! Thx a lot! Now I wish you could explain me somethings in this code...  get in touch with me pls: diegov0@hotmail.com

Comment: another way to get it: 
var searched = from c in xml.Descendants("tbody").Descendants("tr")
select new Time
                               {

                                   nome = c.Descendants("a").First().Value,
                                   pg = Int32.Parse(c.Descendants("td").Where(td => (string)td.Attribute("class") == "pg").First().Value),
=)